# Problem with the payload of captcha-submit request when creating newsession to login to Ebay

Tags: ebay-api, 2captcha, hcaptcha

## Problem with the payload of captcha-submit request when creating newsession to login to Ebay

I'm trying to build a bot to check whether an email is registered or not on Ebay. You may know that if I try to send indentifier request so many times, then the cookies and the crsf token (a part of request's payload, which is got from the sign in page's HTML) are not valid any more. So I need to create a new session (with no cookies), enter the signin page and get the csrf token again. The problem here is that, whenever I create new session, it required to solve Hcaptcha.

I have track the API end point when solving Hcaptcha and there are three main requests: [Captcha submit request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P2CU.png)

This is the cURL (bash) of captcha-submit request: [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/2uanDM/VRPTW-Optimization-Project/main/cURL%20captcha%20submit.txt)

I know where all the parameters in payload come from, except "**guid**" (in captchaTokenInput). If you check in the cookies header of this request, in "cpt", guid is here. But I don't know why the cpt cookies is set, since I have check all the previous requests and 'cpt' does not exist in any Set-Cookies response header

If you want to encounter captcha when enter https://signin.ebay.com/signin/, then delete all cookies first

Can anyone help me to find "guid" to send above request ? Thank you for reading my question